# Always declare local variables

Tags: javascript

W3School saying that All variables used in a function should be declared as `local` variables.

Local variables `must` be declared with the `var` keyword, otherwise they will become `global` variables.

```
function multiply () {
var x = 10; 
var y = 20; 

return x * y;

}; 

function multiply () {
let x = 10; 
let y = 20; 

return x * y;

};
```

But `let` variables in 2nd function are still local variables. 
How local variables declared with other than `var` keyword could become global variables?

Comment: The statement `Local variables must be declared with the var keyword, otherwise they will become global variables.` is wrong - `let` and `const` work just fine too. Best to get your info from somewhere more trustworthy than w3schools.

Comment: variables declared with var has function scope where as variables declared with let has block scope. so may be you misunderstood it or if not then stop reading from that site

Comment: I suspect the intention of the statement is to distinguish between an explicit variable declaration: `var x = 10;` and an implicit variable declaration: `x = 10;`.

Comment: what it clearly means, in context, is just that "local variables must be declared". [Which is absolutely good advice!] At one point (3-4 years ago, or more), the only way to declare a variable was with `var`, so the statement made sense then. It's obviously never been updated to note that you can also now declare a variable with `let` or `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How local variables declared with other than var keyword could become global variables?

They cannot. Every variable declared with `var`, `let` or `const` will be scoped to the current (function / block) scope. W3Schools is just a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Let and const came into picture after es6. They are mainly used to add block scope to a variable. Using the Javascript MDN will give you a clear picture about how exactly both these keywords work.

"Local variables must be declared with the var keyword, otherwise they will become global variables". This statement is no longer correct, your source of information might be outdated.

https://hackernoon.com/js-var-let-or-const-67e51dbb716f - this article might help.